# Really new to XCode. Why won't the thing run?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I'm trying to follow the April 2009 and Winter 2010 Stanford iPhone app development videos and I'm running up against the same problems with both.

First, they don't appear to be using the latest version of XCode - the Outlets and Actions panels are in a different window and there is little info on the net about this (other than one other post on S.O.F.)

Second, having got to the point where I've managed to connect the slider, label and changedLabelText connections, I save, build and run the app - the simulator loads, the app loads and then promptly closes again.

What's going on?  I have not written any code yet and I still have an app which, while it compiles, does not behave!

Is there a better starting point for an XCode noob than the Stanford vids?

Thanks,

Matt.

Comment: If you startup the console and check whats being logged you may get a clue of what's happening. Maybe I am old fashioned but I think getting a book or two is a good idea as well.

Comment: Fair enough, waiting til I get paid to buy a book on this though. Really thought it would be easy enough to get this first app running. The message in the console is: "this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key slider"

Comment: Hey, that message may be the reason. Can you try with other basic apps on the internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so it turns out that I missed one small but important point at the beginning of the video...

When the actions and outlets get created they have to get created on the Object. What I missed is that this means that in the current version of XCode (I'm using 3.2) the Object (renamed to 'Controller' in the video) must be selected in the top panel of the Library window.

The bottom half is where the actions and outlets are created for that Object. I believe that this is the editing process which creates a class called Controller, with certain values and properties - those being the actions and outlets.

Once the class is given a base class of NSObject (he nearly misses it in the video) and writes the content of the method/function (whatever you like to call it) which sets the value of the label, then the whole thing works.

Thanks for pointing me towards the Console - googling what came up in there was very useful.